# Accessing class instance from worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, class

I made a class module `ComplicatedCalculation`.

I have several worksheets which need their own instance of `ComplicatedCalculation`, initialized to slightly parameters in each sheet.

Each `ComplicatedCalculation` has a function `function do_calc(rng as Range)` which outputs an answer based on additional inputs from the worksheet.

```vb
Public cc_for_Sheet1 as New ComplicatedCalculation
Public cc_for_Sheet2 as New ComplicatedCalculation
Public cc_for_Sheet3 as New ComplicatedCalculation
```

How can each worksheet access its own `cc`?

Solutions I considered seem ugly

I don't like this because I don't want the user to fuss about specifying the correct worksheet when trying to call do_calc. It always has to be the worksheet they are using.

```vb
Function do_calc(rng as Range, ws_name as String)
    Dim cc as ComplicatedCalculation
    if ws_name = "Sheet1" then
        cc = cc_for_Sheet1
    elif...
    end if
    do_calc = cc.do_calc(rng)
End Function
```

I don't like this because I'm worried the code will break when someone does Ctrl+Alt+F9 (workbook refresh), or innocently changes the worksheet name.

```vb
Function do_calc(rng as Range)
    Dim cc as ComplicatedCalculation
    if Application.ActiveSheet.name = "Sheet1" then
        cc = cc_for_Sheet1
    elif
    end if
    do_calc = cc.do_calc(rng)
end function
```

Comment: `Application.ThisCell` (in a function called from a worksheet) returns the cell where the UDF was entered.  You should always use that and not `ActiveSheet` if you want to know which worksheet you're getting the call from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.ThisCell` or `Application.Caller` (in a function called from a worksheet) both return the cell where the UDF was entered. You should always use one of those methods and not `ActiveSheet` if you want to know where your UDF code is getting called from.

If you store your calculation objects in a global dictionary keyed to each worksheet, you can do something like this

```
Public calcs As Object

'Set up calculation class instances
Sub InitCalcs()
    Dim cc as ComplicatedCalculation
    Set calcs = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'initialize dictionary

    'Initialize and configure each instance of `cc` and
    ' store in the dictionary like
    calcs.add ws, cc
    '...where ws is the associated worksheet reference and cc the configured object
    
End Sub

'UDF called from worksheet
Function do_calc(rng As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = Application.ThisCell.Worksheet 'calling worksheet
    
    If calcs.Exists(ws) Then  'calculation object for this sheet exists?
        do_calc = calcs(ws).docalc(rng)
    Else
        do_calc = "not configured!"
    End If
   
End Function
```

Comment: Much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If this was useful in resolving your problem, please flag as "Accepted" to help out anyone else coming along later with a similar question.